# When the prolog returns sat as an output what does it mean?

Tags: prolog

When I run my code it returns the sat as the output ? Is it trying to convey an error or what does the output means ?

```
 %Scenario 2:
 %Amy: “My report is original.”
 %Brian: “Mine as well”
 report(2, [Amy,Brian]) :-
    sat(Amy=:=Amy),
    sat(Brian=:=Brian),
  write('1 they are telling the truth , 0 they are lying').
```

The output that I get is :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not trying to convey you an error, it is being as specific as it can be. That is `sat(Amy=:=Amy), sat(Brian=:=Brian)` is satisfiable whenever `sat(Amy=:=Amy)` and `sat(Brian=:=Brian)`.

CLP(B) does not automatically designate variables in expressions to be boolean. You can use `labeling(+Vs)` to inform it as follows:

```
?- use_module(library(clpb)).
?- sat(Amy=:=Amy), sat(Brian=:=Brian), labeling([X,Y]).
X = Y, Y = 0,
sat(Amy=:=Amy),
sat(Brian=:=Brian)
```

This is only the first solution you can use backtrack to obtain the others.